# Check all function arguments

Tags: php

I've been wondering how I could check all my parameters efficiently in any function in a clean and concise way.
I've come up with :

```
function fooBar($myArg, $mySecondArg, $myOptionnalArg = "defaultValue"){
    if(!isset($myArg, $mySecondArg, $myOptionnalArg){
        die(__FUNCTION__ . ":missing parameter");
    }

    if(empty($myArg, $mySecondArg, $myOptionnalArg){
        die(__FUNCTION__ . ":empty parameter");
    }
    //Do stuff
}
```

What I'm looking for is more like:

```
function fooBar($myArg, $mySecondArg, $myOptionnalArg = "defaultValue"){
    $argArray = func_get_args();
    foreach($argArray as $a){
        if(empty($a)){
            die(__FUNCTION__.":".get_arg_name($a)."is empty");
        }        
        if(!isset($a)){
            die(__FUNCTION__.":".get_arg_name($a)."is unset");
        }    
    }
    //Do stuff
}
```

Wich doesn't work since `get_arg_name();` is pure fiction, and `func_get_args();` returns the actual parameters, rather than the ones defined in the prototype.

Could someone give me a hint about it? Any other good/clean way to achieve that is also welcome. 
Thanks

Comment: Don't you think you should ensure that arguments are valid *before* you invoke the function with the mentioned arguments? A function should do as little work as possible, keeping the code clean and decoupled as much as possible. As soon as you want to check whether the arguments fit some scheme (whether they're empty or not set etc.), from within the function.. something smells bad. You can type hint the arguments to make your functions more type-aware, but check the variables before calling the function, not after.

Comment: @NB, validating preconditions is pretty common, at least in the "outer crust functions".

Comment: Dunnow if my habits are bad or not. But I'm used to function that crash if they don't get the parameters they expect. Writing `sum("a string","anotherstring");` should not be possible in my opinion. I'm looking for a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [reflection](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) only. Some example:

```
function test($a, $b, $c) {
  $function = new ReflectionFunction(__FUNCTION__);
  $parameters = $function->getParameters();

  print_r($parameters);
}

test(0, 1, 2);
```

You will see something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ReflectionParameter Object
        (
            [name] => a
        )

    [1] => ReflectionParameter Object
        (
            [name] => b
        )

    [2] => ReflectionParameter Object
        (
            [name] => c
        )

)
```

Comment: That's  exactly what I was looking for. But as far as I read, performance is worth mentionning.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to get what you need with using php reflection:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Please, read more about how to use it.

Comment: This is correct, although I'll add that reflection is kinda slow. I feel the performance is worth mentioning because someone may adopt the usage of such code in many of their php functions.

Comment: You can do the reflection only if you have any errors, but not all the time!, so there will be no performance issues about it. Just do it properly.

Comment: Incorrect. An error doesn't always result from invalid arguments.